# Accessing custom python modules defined in AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

There is an AWS lambda with a layer defined. From the lambda I try to access a custom python package defined in the layer, but it doesn't seem to be there.
Is it even possible to share code that is stored in the layer package and if yes then how?

I would imagine something like this:

```
/layer-dir
  /my-package
    /__init__.py
    /something.py

/lambda-dir
  /__init__.py
  /handler.py
```

and then in `handler.py` there would be something like this:

```
from my-package import something
```

Comment: This should be pretty straight forward, have you uploaded your layer zip?

Comment: Also, as stated by the docs, make sure the structure of your layer zip is **python/my-package/some_file.py**

Comment: @AlexK The second comment was exactly what it was =)

Comment: I will add it as answer since this is a new concept, maybe people would have use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of the uploaded `layer.zip` should be as stated by the [documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) (different depending on the runtime) for **Python**:

```
/python
  /my-package
    /__init__.py
    /something.py
```